# Show is not a member of 'WpfApplication1.Page2'

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I just want to switch between `WPF` pages, but getting above mentioned error: 
**"Show is not a member of WpfApplication1.Page2"**.
here is my code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Class Page1

'  Private Property Page2 As WpfApplication1.Page2

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn1.Click


    Dim dd As New Page2
    dd.Show(Me)
    'dd.ShowDialog(Me)

    Me.txt1.Text = (dd.txt10.Text)
End Sub
End Class
```

page 2 xaml code

```
<Page x:Class="Page2"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page2">
<Grid>

    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" Height="55"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="38,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

page2 behind code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Class Page2

End Class

Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This means your `Page2` is not a (valid) window. Please post the first lines of the `XAML` and the code behind. You need to make sure you are inheriting from `Window`...

Comment: Your issue is because it's `Page` in your `XAML` code behind. You need to use `Window` In your code behind in `Page2` you need to inherit `Window`

Comment: who to inherit Window please guide me in this regard i shell be very thankful to you

Answer (score -1):

Dim dd As New Page2

Me.Content = dd

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
know this error occur

Comment: {"Page can have only Window or Frame as parent."}
in detail this message appeared

Comment: This isn't a complete answer; you do not explain what this does. Please describe in your answer what this does.

Comment: what is this to me or to user2435645
This isn't a complete answer; you do not explain what this does. Please describe in your answer what this does. –  436f6465786572 4 mins ago

Comment: @SoniaRehman I am telling him he need's to update his answer to explain what it does and how it might work to fix your issue. Just looking at his proposed answer doesn't help anyone that see's it.

Comment: @ Unnamed person (436f6465786572) ok i update my question please review it?